# How to access aws config file from WSL (Windows subsystem for Linux)?

Tags: windows, bash, amazon-web-services, aws-cli, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have installed awscli and have added aws keys to the config and credentials file.
Now I can access them through file explorer from Windows but I cannot access them through the WSL bash. It says permission denied when I try to cd to the .aws folder present in rootfs. How do I access them from bash?

Comment: I'd expect them be under /home/yourname/.aws/ when in WSL.

Comment: Just run `aws configure` and enter your credentials. Now they will be stored correctly under WSL.

Comment: @jarmod This is what i get 
thedreamsaver@MSI:/mnt/c/Users/thedreamsaver$ cd .aws
-bash: cd: .aws: No such file or directory

Comment: @JohnHanley yeah they do but just in case I want to edit those files in WSl. Can I not navigate to them?

Comment: The Linux user’s home directory is not the same as the Windows user’s home directory.

Comment: Yes, you cant edit the AWS Windows Credentials file, but from WSL the AWS CLI will not see or care about those changes. I don't have WSL running on my laptop, but the path would be like: /<windows_mount_point>/Users/<user_name>/.aws/credentials

Comment: Yeah I too was expecting that @JohnHanley but getting 
thedreamsaver@MSI:/mnt/c/Users/thedreamsaver$ cd .aws 
-bash: cd: .aws: No such file or directory

when I try to access that

Comment: Check when using a normal Windows user account if `~/.aws` exists and then check for `~/.aws/credentials`. Replace `~` with the correct `c:\Users\<username>\` path.

Answer (score 46):

All you have to do is to set a couple of environment variables from the WSL shell. I am assuming that you are working with bash and Ubuntu.

```
export AWS_SHARED_CREDENTIALS_FILE=/mnt/c/Users/<your user name>/.aws/credentials
export AWS_CONFIG_FILE=/mnt/c/Users/<your user name>/.aws/config
```

If you want to make the env variables sticky add the two lines to ~/.bashrc
or /etc/bash.bashrc

remember to `source /etc/bash.bashrc` *or*  `source ~/.bashrc` after editing them.

See documentation here complete list of env variables you can work with [cli-environment](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-environment.html)

Comment: This is great. So you manage to use the same profiles and credentials in both systems.

Comment: That solution worked for me, but only after running "wsl --shutdown" from windows PowerShell with admin privileges and reconnecting to WSL bash

Comment: The path is not same for everyone. So for those, if the verified answer does not work, try to navigate to the path manually and then run the commands.

Comment: It didn't work for me at first but when I switched from Windows format (CR LF) to to Unix (LF) it worked as a charm. For those who don't know - you can easily change the format in Notepad++

Answer (score 1):

It would seem to me that setting `AWS_SHARED_CREDENTIALS_FILE` and `AWS_CONFIG_FILE`, as explained in the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53083079), is the most elegant approach. However I just now followed the [AWS CLI Linux installation instructions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/getting-started-install.html), which say to use the following commands, which executes a downloaded script:

```bash
curl "https://awscli.amazonaws.com/awscli-exe-linux-x86_64.zip" -o "awscliv2.zip"
unzip awscliv2.zip
sudo ./aws/install
```

The script must have detected that I was running in WSL, because apparently it created a WSL symlink of `~/.aws` to `/mnt/c/Users/user/.aws`, which has equivalent results to using the environment variables. And since this approach is reasonable as well, I don't feel there's a need to use the energy to switch to the environment variable approach.

*Note: I'm not entirely certain that the `awscliv2.zip` installer made these changes. I first tried installing the AWS CLI in WSL using `sudo apt install awscli` before realizing that it installed v1.x instead of v2.x, so I uninstalled it and used the approach described here. Maybe someone can verify the behavior and confirm in the comments what command added the symlink.*

Comment: I have just faced the same simlink and cannot figure out the way it was created.